# toolstripbutton remove lighting

Tags: c#, toolstrip, mousehover, toolstripbutton

I have a toolstripbutton into my toolstrip, and I wish remove the orange lighting when a mouse is hover, because I change the picture of the button dynamically..

How can I do this?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/d27664a6-4564-4442-84f4-2034541bbd5e/

Answer (score 0):

Your English is impeccably bad so ill try to interpret as best i can.

I'm assuming you wish to change the image of a toolstripbutton once it's been clicked.
This is quite simple.
All you have to do is create an onClick action for the button, then change its icon/image attribute through code within the onClick action function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('enter your element or class here').css("src", "path to image");
})
```